# Send email with TDD Laravel 5.6

Tags: testing, laravel-5, phpunit, tdd

I am doing the registration user

```
public function register(RegistrationUser $request)
{
  $user = $this->usersRepo->create($request->all());

  $user->activation_token = str_random(48);
  $user->save();

  Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new ActivationAccount($user->first_name, $user->last_name, $user->email, $request->input('password'), $url));

  return redirect()->route('successful.registration')

}
```

My registration test is:

```
 public function it_creates_a_new_user()
{

    $this->withExceptionHandling();

    $response = $this->get(route('register'))
        ->assertStatus(200);

    $this->post('register', [
        'first_name' => 'Juan',
        'last_name' => 'Lopez',            
        'email' => 'jlopez@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'activation_tone' => str_random(48)
    ])->assertRedirect(route('successful.registration'));

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
        'email' => 'jlopez@gmail.com',
    ]);

  }
```

I have two questions:

1) How can I write a test to send the registration email and verify that it sends and arrives well?

2) When the user clicks on his email he calls a method where the activation token is passed to activate his account

Answer (score 1):

1. In my opinion you should use mail fake ,which will prevent mail from being sent. You may then assert that mailables were sent to users and even inspect the data they received.

   please read laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mocking#mail-fake
2. There must be a route which is handling activation token and functionality, so try to get the token and call route with specific token

Note: As a developer we need to make sure that our code works which our tests are confirming, Sending and delivering email should be not be covered as they considered to work as expected(by any email service provider).